# Disable suspend/sleep mode completely on Fedora 21

Tags: fedora, power-management

I connect to a Fedora 21 workstation with SSH, but after several minutes not using the connection the system go to sleep and I loose my connection.

So how can I disallow completely the system to go into suspend/sleep mode ?

Comment: Do you see the remote system suspend or sleep? I also noticed SSH connections to drop the link after a while idle. I solved this issue by installing and using `screen` on the remote machine. Might work for you as well.

Comment: The system go to sleep (no more log during the sleep time) and the nic came down. So using screen will not help me.

Comment: Then disable power savings in your power management applet. The name of the latter depends on what desktop environment you are using: KDE, GNOME, Xfce, LXDE...

Comment: The F21 system actually goes into some powersave mode?  Or does the F21 SSH server just drop the connection due to inactivity?  Have you tried setting a `ServerAliveInterval`?

Comment: The F21 system goes into PM Mode and before entering sleep mode F21 stop the network interface. As i don't log into the Graphical environment (the server is in multi-user target, not graphical.target) changing option in desktop environment like GNOME, KDE, will not help.

Answer (score 3):

I resolv my problem with creating a init.d script that use the systemd-inhibit command:

```
#!/bin/bash

nohup systemd-inhibit --why="Disable sleep" --mode=block /usr/bin/bash -c "while true; do sleep 120; done" >/dev/null 2>&1 &

exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
sudo systemctl mask suspend.target
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target
```

because:
Systemd manages all of this. There's a million ways for something to trigger a shutdown, including gnome/kde, `NetworkManager` and of course systemd itself. The sleep and suspend targets, just like shutdown are "static" i.e. core built-in units that can not be disabled. You can however mask them and prevent `systemd` from ever entering them.

Comment: Besides not working on my Fedora 25, these commands actually caused the system to become unstable while sleeping. Whenever I press the "Sleep" button on my keyboard, the screen gets black with strange characters printed each time I press "Sleep" or "Wake" again. Even worse, if I ever manage to get successfully back to my Gnome desktop, all the applications are closed and unsaved work lost. To undo the commands, I simply repeated them with `unmask` instead of `mask`.

Comment: There are no such targets in fedora 26

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Removed `--what=idle` from the command - apparently this is not enough.  The default is `--what=shutdown:sleep:idle`, which works better (but `--what=sleep:idle` should work too).

Old question, but another variant of the systemd-inhibit solution is to put the following in `~/.profile` (in my case, just before byobu is launched).  Then, sleep will be inhibited as long as there are login shells open (i.e. mostly SSH sessions unless you also log in from the non-GUI console).

```
# Inhibit idle sleep.  This background process waits for the current shell to exit.
nohup systemd-inhibit --who=Bash --why="Byobu running" tail --pid=$$ -f /dev/null &
```

I found out about the `tail --pid` part here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41613532/827828